# Uncaught ReferenceError: datapoint is not defined. While calling the json data from an api

Tags: javascript, api, leaflet

I am trying to call the variable datapoints from an api which has data in the JSON Format.
I get the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: datapoint is not defined**

I've used the variable here.

```
     for (var i=0; i<datapoint.length; i++) {

            var lon = datapoint[i][2];
            var lat = datapoint[i][3];
            var popupText = String(datapoint[i][2]);
            var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var marker = new L.marker(markerLocation);
            marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(popupText);
            marker.setOpacity(0.001);
        }
```

Here is how I am calling the api:

```
<script src="http://example.com/vx1/xloc.php?qty=100"></script>
```

JSON Object:

```
{"datapoint":[{"intensity":92,"latitud":"18.52","longitud":"82.4767"},{"intensity":68,"latitud":"17.7375","longitud":"82.8347"}]}
```

Comment: can you also add your JSON object in the post. Also, why are you calling an API through script? use an AJAX or promise instead , and show us the JSON data to validate the issue

Comment: @SumodhNair Added the sample JSON data.

Comment: What does the URL in the `<script>` tag emit?

Comment: @peeebeee JSON data

Comment: Am I right that you get datapoint by `<script....>`?

Comment: datapoint is key inside an object. it won't be accessible directly
you need to replace it with someObj.datapoint in order to access it

Comment: @Sk96 Sorry but i am unable to get your point. What do i add and where?

Comment: The JSON describes an array of objects but doesn't assign it to anything. Best way would be to retrieve it using ajax.

Comment: @renny check the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fetching the values wrong. Please take a leaf out of this code and update your code accordingly

```
fetch('http://example.com/vx1/xloc.php?qty=100')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
        let datapoint = response.datapoint;
        for (let i=0; i<datapoint.length; i++) {

            let lon = datapoint[i]["latitude"];
            let lat = datapoint[i]["longitude"];
         //rest of the code
        }
  });
```

Comment: Your code shows like you're using the local data but i need to fetch it from an api

Comment: for fetching data from an API you need to do an asynchronous call to the server.

Comment: Because it had no ajax and so wasn't a solution the OP could use. Now it does, I've cancelled my downvote.

Comment: Your code seems to be working but still unable to render the heatmap. Now in the heat map part it says datapoint is not defined

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to get the json from the API

```
// create the ajax call
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// set the callback
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {

    // this if mean the call was responded
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

        // this if tell you the request was successful
        // the possible status are the http status code
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            datapoint = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText).datapoint;
            // do your things with datapoint
        }
    }
}

// send the request
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://example.com/vx1/xloc.php?qty=100');
httpRequest.send();
```

more on [http status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

---

If someone want's to edit to add jQuery's version, you're welcome (I'm no good with jQuery) (startpoint : [$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/vx1/xloc.php?qty=100', function(data) {
   $.each (data, function (i, item) {
   // Do things with item.datapoint
    });
});
```